# How can the standard AppPool identity have permission to pop up a debugger window

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, iis, debugging

I've tried to add

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
```

to my IIS ASP.NET web site code. I run the application as the standard AppPoolIdentity user and it pops up a debug window where I can choose to attach VS2010 and debug the process. My question is, what allows the AppPoolIdentity (virtual) user permission to interact with my desktop? Normally that's not allowed. This was tested on Windows 7 x64.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an unhandled exception occurs, there is a check done in the registry to see which debugger is listed.

32 bit systems use:
KEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug\Debugger

This can also be the source of a security vulnerability - see
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/923827

for details on the AEDebug registry key see:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hs4b7a6.aspx

The app pool identity isn't interacting with your desktop - the debugger request is. Nothing has 'interacted' until you choose to debug, at that time the debugger is launched and you attach to that process.

Comment: That is very good information. But one question persists, who does it find "my" user session? What if two users are logged in, will both get the JIT debugger prompt?

Comment: I believe the "console" session will always get this (session 0). If a user is not logged on, there is a specific message it fails with (Debugger could not be started because no user is logged on.)

Comment: That probably makes sense. Thanks, the answer is yours!

Answer (score 0):

The easist thing to do is in VS attach to process, choose IIS. You can set a breakpoint in your app and it will stop on the breakpoint. It will stop every web site on your pc too!!!!

The other thing you can do is set the debugging mode on your app. The default is just my code. Tell it to debug native code too.

here was a question like yours
[How to start aspnet_wp.exe without firing Application_Start event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436941/how-to-start-aspnet-wp-exe-without-firing-application-start-event)

Comment: My question wasn't how to do it (I already do it), but rather why it works, why Windows allows it, when I would expect the ASPNET user to not have access to my desktop.